# Java Exception : length of java.version string lower than 2 : 10

Tags: java, executable-jar

I tried to open a jar file in windows but it didn't open.
I used "java.exe -jar" command in cmd to open the jar file and the following message appeared :

```
Exception in thread "main" junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: length of java.version string lower than 2 : 10
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:372)
...
```

What is the problem and how can I open this jar file?
By the way I have jre-10 installed.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code (a [mcve]), we can't help you. This is not a Java problem, but either a specific failure of a test, or a bug in a library you use.

Comment: This reminds me of the rumors why windows 10 was not called Windows 9: `if (version.startsWith("9")) /* We're on 95 or 98 here */` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the jar is doing a string compare on the java version to make sure it's >= '2' which is now failing because '10' < '2' although 10 > 2. Try running it with jre 9.

Comment: Yeah but... why. Should try to understand what exactly is causing this. The next releases of Java will bring some features, would be sad to stay on Java 9 (which will stop being supported relatively soon) just for this.

Comment: Ask the company that built the JAR for an update (maybe easier said than done, though).

Answer (score 1):

The classes in your JAR file may have been compiled using a later version of Java than the version of Java you are attempting to run with. To confirm, try executing with a later version of Java or rebuilding with an earlier version of javac.